# authenticate blackberry application with facebook account

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am developing an application where user can register themselves by filling up the registration form or login with their facebook account to use the application. But my problem is- how can I hit the login page of facebook and retrieve the userid, token, session key, username etc when user successfully logins to his facebook account and then redirect him back to my application.

I am really confused searching here and there. I have to just authenticate my user with his facebook account and comeback to my application with userid and all the keys.

please help.

Kind Regards,
Rupesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Facebook supports OpenID, so use that. A quick google brings up articles such as http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/246/